# Calculate using Rational Index Binomial Theorem in C

Tags: c, math

I have tried so many ways to calculate using this binomial theorem but I still couldn't find one:

[image: Rational index binomial theorem]

The value of x and n is given for example b=0.5 and n=8

I know for the factorial we have to use loop but the numerator part is a little bit tricky.

Obviously I know how to code for (1+b)^n, but the question is still asking for the coding for binom theorem.

For example if the value of x is 0<x<1 and n is any positive integer, what will the value of (1+x)^n will be using the binomial theorem?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225149/discussion-on-question-by-bilah-calculate-using-rational-index-binomial-theorem).

Comment: Hi bilah. Thanks for editing. But as you can see, the question has still been closed for making the programming problem you encountered not obvious enough. Please edit again and explain the specific problem. (Feel free to confirm the assumptions I describe in my answer as "I understand ...", by more or less quoting them.) Showing code attempts would also be great help. You probably have an endless loop implemented...

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you know how to calculate the left side of the equation in programming.
I understand that you also know how to program the right side, apart from the problem that it is an infinite loop; but you want it to end at some point and have a result.
By the math theory ending early means a wrong result.
But in programming you will have problems with restricted precision of floating point math anyway. So you can take shortcuts to solve your problem.

In the comments you find recommendations how to do the calculation of each step efficiently. I will only focus on the end condition.

Write a loop calculating more and more precise steps.
End the loop when a freshly calculated (intermediate) result is the same as the previous one. With floating point representation having restricted precision that will sooner or later happen and the result will be within only one "minimal rounding" of the correct result.

Note:
In order to avoid the restricted precision getting in the way at the wrong place, I recommend to calculate the parts (as described in the recommendation in comments) in `double` and the intermediate results (those you compare for the loop condition) into a `float` variable.

Comment: I chose to ignore the "ASAP" in the comments. But please understand https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest